# reuse DOM object selected by Query

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have links (HTML `a` tags) on pages which use "symbolic" links, such as:
`gotoCourse&courseId=12`

When a use clicks on such a link, I have used JQuery to add a click event and that click event triggers an AJAX request using the symbolic link as parameter.
Then a process is run on the server using this parameter, and then there are two possibilities.

1. Everything has been checked (such as course with courseId 12 exists, logged in user is allowed to go to this course). My AJAX request then returns a JSON string with `status` set to `true` and `message` set to the real URL I want to redirect the user to.
2. At least one check has failed (such as course with courseId 12 does not exist, logged in user is not allowed to go to this course). My AJAX request then returns a JSON string with `status` set to `false` and `message` set to relevant error message.

The `onclick` event and the AJAX request just work fine.

I also know how to get the `status` and the `message` from AJAX response.

What I am looking for is: how, once the function declared on the click has been processed, can I start a new process based on the `status` received in AJAX response? Meaning:

1. If the `status` is `true`, change the `href` of the `a` tag and set it to the URL provided in the `message`. This has to be done on the DOM node on which the click event has been added. To be maybe more specific, how can I give to the function which performs the AJAX call, the reference of the current DOM object, so that this function can then change the `href` attribute of this DOM object?
2. If the `status` is `false`, use alertify.js to display an alert using the text provided in the `message`.

Please advise.

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Declare a function which takes the ajax result (`status` and `message`) and the DOM object reference. Call that function within your click event handler and pass `this` for the DOM object parameter. In that function do whatever you need to.